# Is there a way to get two specific data together in a nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this array that's a response from an endpoint that looks like this:

```
{
  "dates": [
    {
      "date": "02-06-2021",
      "product": [
        {
          "id": "a1",
          "quantity": 10,
          "price": 10.99
         ]
        },
        {
          "id": "b2",
          "quantity": 43,
          "price": 17.99
        ]
       }]
    }
```

Is there a way where we can simply get the id and quantity for each product together?
I know how to get it separately but not sure if it's possible to get it together:

```
var fetchData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var idData = JSON.parse(fetchData.getContentText());
var getIdData = idData.dates.map(dates => {return dates.product.map(product => {return product.id})});

var getQuantityData = idData.dates.map(dates => {return dates.product.map(product => {return product.quantity})});
```

Comment: _"Is there a way..."_ - Not with that invalid syntax...

Comment: @Andreas hey at which part is it invalid? works fine for me. im wondering if can get it together instead of separately

Comment: You could just map product objects.

Comment: _"at which part?"_ - The given input (response) is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iData = JSON.parse('{"dates":[{"date":"02-06-2021","product":[{"id":"a1","quantity":10,"price":10.99},{"id":"b2","quantity":43,"price":17.99}]}]}')
let A = idData.dates[0].product.map(obj => [obj.id,obj.quantity]);
A.unshift(['id','Quantity']);
```

A will be a two column 2 dimensional array that can be put into a spreadsheet with setValues() method.

```
sheet.getRange( 1,1,A.length,A[0].length).setValues(A);
```

Here's the entire function after fixing the sample JSON.

```
function testt() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  const idData = JSON.parse('{"dates":[{"date":"02-06-2021","product":[{"id":"a1","quantity":10,"price":10.99},{"id":"b2","quantity":43,"price":17.99}]}]}');
  let A = idData.dates[0].product.map(obj => [obj.id, obj.quantity]);
  A.unshift(['id', 'Quantity']);
  sh.getRange(1, 1, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
}
```

Output:

| id | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 10 |
| b2 | 43 |

Comment: oh this is nice! thank you. will try it out

Comment: `.map(({id, quantitiy}) => [ id, quantity ])`

Comment: works like a charm! thanks for the detail explanation as well. i really appreciate it. thank you :)